process is not defined -- ReferenceError
Resolving the "process is not defined" error in a Create React App project required configuring webpack's resolve.fallback option to provide polyfills or mock implementations for Node.js core modules that are not available in the browser environment.
const { override } = require('customize-cra');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = override((config) => {
  config.resolve.fallback = {
    ...config.resolve.fallback,
    'process': false, // Set 'process' to false instead of using a mock
    'zlib': require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
    'querystring': require.resolve('querystring-es3'),
    'stream': require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
    'path': require.resolve('path-browserify'),
    'fs': false,
    'timers': require.resolve('timers-browserify'),
    'crypto': require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    'http': require.resolve('stream-http'),
    'https': require.resolve('https-browserify'),
    'net': require.resolve('net-browserify'),
    'url': require.resolve('url/'),
    'assert': require.resolve('assert/'),
    'vm': require.resolve('vm-browserify'),
    'async_hooks': false,
    'child_process': false,
  };

  // Exclude the 'destroy' package
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\/node_modules\/destroy\//,
    use: 'null-loader',
  });

  // Resolve conflicting values for 'process.env'
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'debug',
    })
  );

  return config;
});

Error That i Get
process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:130687:18)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:227078:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226477:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226736:21)
    at ./node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:131512:20)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:227078:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226477:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226736:21)
    at ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33021:14)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:227078:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226477:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226736:21)
    at ./node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40757:12)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:227078:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226477:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226736:21)
    at ./node_modules/etag/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58075:14)
    at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:227078:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226477:32)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:226736:21)


Would it need to be config.resolve.fallback.process...?

You'll need to trace what is using readable-stream, whatever that options.factory function is; it's probably code that is not browser compatible. The call stack should help you figure out where the code lives.
